# Passing variables between two JavaScript modules not working

Tags: javascript, module

I have two modules within the same `namespace`, and I want to pass a variable between them. The namespace is called `app`, and the variable is `a` - but for some reason my variable `a` always comes out `null` when my method is called.

Here is the code:

```
// module 1
(function() {
    app.module1 = (function() {
        var a = null; 
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
            a = { message: hallo };
            app.module2.print();
        }, 0);

        return {
            a: a
        };
    })();
})();

// module 2

(function() {
    app.module2 = (function() {
        var print = function() {
            console.log(app.module1.a);
        }

        return {
            print: print
        };
    })();
})();
```

Comment: Did you mean to have `a = { message: "hallo" };`? Where `hallo` becomes a string? Or is that defined somewhere off the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/alefix/1/edit)

Basically what you can do is to calculate variable each time:

In your module 1:

```
a: function(){return a;}
```

Wherever you are using a:

```
console.log(app.module1.a());
```

Comment: console prints ERROR: a is not a function

Answer (score 1):

It's because your handler is referring to the local `a` and not the `a` property on the module. I suggest you modify the object instead, or you could do this:

```
// module 1
(function () {
  app.module1 = (function () {
    var interface = {
      a: null
    };
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
      //this way, you are modifying the object
      interface.a = {
        message: hallo
      };
      app.module2.print();
    }, 0);
    return interface;
  })();
})();
```